# Silverlight 4 OOB blank screen

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I have a working web application which I want to use as OOB;
However, when I install it, all I get is a blank screen and nothing more...

I also tried without any javascript or HtmlPage.Methods invokes, but still the same

Please help

Comment: What is an OOB?  I've used Silverlight, but I've never seen the OOB acronym.

Comment: @quanticle - OOB - Out of Browser.  It's available for Silverlight 4 and 3 (in some limit capacity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Make sure you are running the app in debug mode (set it to start in OOB from the project settings and set the project and not the website to be the startup project). If you do that, you should be able to step into where the problem occurs.*

(https://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/190044.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

(A very late reply but the solution wasn't easily available so posting this to help anyone who needs help on this) I was having a problem with the white screen happening when launching OOB apps in debug mode. From lots of searching it appeared that the white screen occurs when an exception is thrown during the application start. Hence the app appearing to load correctly at first and then suddenly going to white screen. I found that the following line of code from the default business app template (from Application_Startup in App.xaml.cs) was causing the exception in OOB mode when using forms authentication:

```
WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoadUser(this.Application_UserLoaded, null);
```

Commenting out the line of code immediately made the white screen problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say what is wrong in your case because you haven't provided any sources, but you can use this article as a reference [Building An Out-of-Browser Client With Silverlight 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882515.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to interact with page *right before* InitializeComponent() call in constructor of your main UserControl. If some exception occured before InitializeComponent() then you'll receive blank screen.